# Distinct behavior of a python code with two different dictionaries. Why its happening?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have write down a simple code to sort a dictionary,

```
D1 = {2:3, 1:89, 4:5, 3:0}
sort_dic = {}
print sorted(D1)
for i in sorted(D1):
    sort_dic.update({i:D1[i]})
print sort_dic
```

Which works fine and generates desired output:

```
{1: 89, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 5}
```

but when, I have changed the dictionary, It won't work and never sorting the dictionary, showing a strange behavior without invoking an error:

```
 D1 = {307: 'LYS', 309: 'ARG', 86: 'GLU', 88: 'VAL', 92: 'ASN', 61: 'ILE', 111: 'ARG'}
 sort_dic = {}
 print sorted(D1)
 for i in sorted(D1):
      sort_dic.update({i:D1[i]})
 print sort_dic
```

result with this:

```
{307: 'LYS', 309: 'ARG', 86: 'GLU', 88: 'VAL', 92: 'ASN', 61: 'ILE', 111: 'ARG'}
```

thanks for help

Update: Thanks for the code but in this case my main concern Is to understand the distinct behavior of a code with two different  dictionaries. Why its happening. Kindly, explain.

Comment: Why do you want your dictionary to be sorted?

Comment: I don't need any code rather  in this case my main concern Is to understand the distinct behavior of a code with two different dictionaries. Why its happening. Kindly, explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on dictionaries to remain in any particular order. Instead you should use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(D1.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

An `OrderedDict` remembers it's insertion order, so when you add new entries you will need to sort it again, unless you know that the new entries belong at the "end" of your dictionary.

Comment: Update: Thanks for the code but in this case my main concern Is to understand the distinct behavior of a code with two different dictionaries. Why its happening. Kindly, explain.

Comment: @jax unless you use an OrderedDict the order of items in a dictionary can change at any point. This is typical of dictionaries in many languages.

Comment: Ok,  so we cant control the order of a dictionary without putting an extra force like "OrderedDict" :)

Comment: @jax That's right, you need the OrderedDict to achieve this. If this answers your question please "accept" this answer (the tick mark under the voting arrows).

Comment: just for the sake of my curiosity, why did dictionary in the first case able to maintain its order but not in second case.

Comment: @jax cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary